# Finding a formula in terms of matrix elements of linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

I have been given this problem:

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Find a formula for $\|T\|$ in terms of the matrix elements of $T$. Prove your formula, and illustrate it with an example.

(where $\|T\| = \sup(|Tx|:|x|=1)$)

So I know that if the transformation goes from 1 to n then the corresponding matrix is an n x 1 matrix, where $|Tx|$ can be found through the square root of the sum of the squares. I think my inuition is correct, however I'm not exactly sure how to put this into a formula, and definitely not sure how to prove it.

Comment: How many points are there on the real line with $|x|=1$? And $T$ is linear, so that simplifies things.

Comment: I think there are only two, x= 1 and -1. This doesn't really help me with my problem of creating a formula using the matrix elements of T. I'm not even sure what the formula would look like (other than the obvious that it is linear)

Comment: Of course it helps. $\|T\| = \max(|T(1)|,|T(-1)|)$ and you know that $T(-1) = -T(1)$ so the formula is $\|T\| = |T(1)|$. Compute $|T(1)|$ however you wish, it depends on the norm you are using.